# swiftui text, how can I pass a bool value to func hidden ()

Tags: swiftui

In swiftui text there is a function called hidden (). When I set this function, the text is invisible. So far everything is fine. Now I want it to be invisible only if a Bool value is set. Unfortunately, I can not pass a bool value.

```
Text("Bitte Password eingeben")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 50, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .hidden()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return the `.hidden()` version of the view when some state is enabled like this (note that the hidden version and non hidden version are two different types which is why the type eraser is necessary -- `some View` means all exists from the function must return the same type that conforms to View):

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isHidden = false
    var body: some View {
        let text = Text("Bitte Password eingeben")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 50, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .textContentType(.password)
        return isHidden ? AnyView(text) : AnyView(text.hidden())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written a little extension on `View`, because I find it quite surprising that `hidden()` doesn't take a parameter:

```
extension View {

    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        if hidden {
            return self.hidden().eraseToAnyView()
        } else {
            return self.eraseToAnyView()
        } 
    }

    func eraseToAnyView() -> AnyView {
        return AnyView(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a very nice little extension, though I need to turn "eraseToAnyView" to "AnyView(self.hidden())" etc. for it to work